# Creating a script to remove a reference

Tags: bash, shell

I have an issue with my project and need to always run a command to delete a particular reference. I have a `Run Script` which runs everytime when the project build but how can I structure my write this in my script

`nano "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXX/Pods-XXXX-resources-Development-output-files.xcfilelist"`

then delete this line if it exist

`${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car`

any help on what the script can look like would be helpful.

I know I can remove any text that has car like

`sed -i -e '/car/d' .bash_profile` but now the need to first nano into that `xcfilelist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sed -i -e '/car/d' "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXX/Pods-XXXX-resources-Development-output-files.xcfilelist"
```